# Need help on PREPARE sql function PDO

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble running mysql using PREPARE statement. I keep getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function PREPARE() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\classes\class.ManageSales.php on line 16

Here's my `class.ManageSales.php`:

```
class addSales {

    public $sales;
    public $created_on;
    public $created_by;


    public function setSales(array $item) { 

        $conn = new dbconnection();
        $dbh = $conn->connect();

        $this->sales = $item['sales'];
        $this->created_on = $item['created_on'];
        $this->created_by = $item['created_by'];

        $query = $dbh->PREPARE("INSERT INTO tbltransaction(transTypeId,amount,created_on,created_by) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
        $values = array(1,$this->sales,$this->created_on,$this->created_by);            
        $run_query = execute($values);

        $counts = $run_query->rowCount();           
        return $counts;
    }

}
```

My `index.php` is:

```
require_once 'classes/class.Database.php';
require_once 'classes/class.ManageSales.php';

$theSales = new addSales();

$setSales = $theSales->setSales(array(
    'sales' => 1100, 
    'created_on' => '2014-07-14', 
    'created_by' => 'Janus Ian'     
    ));
```

can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Okay, I've updated my setSales() function but i get new error:  Fatal error: Call to undefined function execute() in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\classes\class.ManageSales.php on line 20\class.ManageSales.php on line 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `prepare()` on `$dbh`. But `$dbh` is not defined in your code. I would make `$dbh` a parameter in the `setsales()` function. Then pass `$dbconnect` to the function. That way you are actually calling `prepare()` on the DB.

Comment: Okay i've done that. Now a new error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function execute() in C:\xampp\htdocs\mykarenderia\classes\class.ManageSales.php on line 20

Comment: You have to call execute on the query. So: `$query->execute()`

Answer (score 3):

your database handlder `$dbh` is not defined.  also `prepare` should be lowercase (but that's not the error you're getting now)

/EDIT that code has multiple problems.  the immediate error that you're asking about is what i described above, but once that's done you're going to see more problems.  where's `execute` defined?  do you mean `statement->execute`?  if so, define that.  you're also overwriting `$query` (I think you probably want the first one to be `$statement` but that's just a guess).